# How can I install OpenMP in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, compiling

Im using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. 
I don't know if it makes a difference but CPU's architecture is 64bit (Intel i3).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You don't install OpenMP. OpenMP is a feature of the compiler. Check that the compiler you are using implements OpenMP, which is an API for parallel programming in C/C++/Fortran.

Check with the OpenMP website, openmp.org for a list of compilers and platforms that support OpenMP programming.

Comment: I have installed gcc 4.6 by using the command sudo apt-get install gcc 4.6 and the output is:

Comment: anita@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc-4.6 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 190 not upgraded.

Comment: gcc 4.6 implements version 3.0 of the OpenMP standart. You have to enable it by using: gcc -fopenmp foo.c

Comment: Thank you so much but I had to install the version 11.04 and now the output is: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc-4.5 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 278 not upgraded. The version of the OMP is the same?
 Can I still use the same command?

Comment: In case you ar using the gnu compiler, you can try with `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib`

Comment: so what is the result of "sudo apt-cache search openmp" ?

Answer (score 21):

`sudo apt install libomp-dev`

`apt show libomp-dev`

Description: LLVM OpenMP runtime - dev package
 The runtime is the part of the OpenMP implementation that your code is
 linked against, and that manages the multiple threads in an OpenMP program
 while it is executing.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-cache libomp` and `sudo apt-get install libomp-<version>-dev` ,  replace  with the version that you choose from the list